# If either GET or POST are empty, redirect

Tags: php, redirect

Very strange problem and I'm scratching my head. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated, thanks.

I have a Search Location result page that should only appear if either 1) the form on the previous page has been submitted; or 2) they are searching via a url, e.g.

`www.mywebsite.com?use_url=on&zipcode=UB95BX&radius=50`.

So, at the top of the page I have the following code:

```
// Validate input and sanitize
if (empty($_POST['submit']) || empty($_GET['use_url']))
 {
  header('Location: index1.php');
  exit; 
 }
```

Problem is, it's not working and it's redirecting EVERY request. Does anyone know how I can get it to work, so that if there is no submit post, or if there is no get request (basically, if the user types in `www.mywebsite.com/locations.php` directly into the url bar), the user is redirected.

Strange thing is this, if I leave out the empty($_GET) command and make it therefore

```
// Validate input and sanitize
if (empty($_POST['submit']))
 {
  header('Location: index1.php');
  exit; 
 }
```

It works fine on an empty submit, the problems only occurs when I specify two criteria for a redirect.

Thanks everyone / Luke

Comment: `if (empty($_POST['submit']) && empty($_GET['use_url']))`

Comment: thanks John, I see you were the first but I can't vote for this answer. Much appreciated !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`||` is logical OR. Currently your code reads "if **either** post or get are empty, redirect"

What im sure you mean is "if **both** post and get are empty, redirect".

You should use logical AND (`&&`):

```
if (empty($_POST['submit']) && empty($_GET['use_url']))
{
  header('Location: index1.php');
  exit; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. such a small mistake shows that I still need to develop my coding brain. Now it's plainly obvious!! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (empty($_REQUEST['submit'])
```

or if (!isset($_REQUEST['submit'])